# How to define and prove a bijection function between two set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question when doing an exercise:

> Suppose $E$ is a set with $n$ elements, and we define $P(E)$ as a power set, for example $E=\{1,2\}$, we have $P(E)=\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\},\{1,2\}\}$.

> Now if we fix an element $x \in E$, and we note $Px$ as the power set in $E$ with $x$, and $Qx$ as the power set in $E$ without $x$.

> prove $Px$ and $Qx$ have the same cardinal, and equal $P(E\backslash\{x\})$

Assume we don't know the fact that cardinal of $P(E)$ is $2^n$.

I'm thinking of creat a bijective function between $Px$ and $P(E\backslash\{x\})$  which implies the cardinal is the same. and same for Qx.

But I don't know how to prove that function is bijective.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: In your example $x=1 \in E$ so what does "power set of E with x" mean? Note that 1 is not in the power set of E.

Answer (score 1):

$Qx$ and $P(E\setminus \{x\})$ are actually not just the same size, they are *the same set*. Once you see this, proving that they have the same size is easy.

For bijecting $Px$ and $Qx$, consider the function $Px\to Qx$ given by "remove $x$". What do you think the inverse function might be?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and aid. Do you mean that the inverse function of $Px \to Qx$ is "add x"? But in this case, how to write a formal proof? Sorry for this silly question